# In Stata, how can I combine box plots of different widths?

Tags: graphics, stata

I'm trying to combine several box plots across categories of different size.
Here is an example illustrating problem:

```
sysuse auto

graph box mpg, by(rep78, rows(1)) name(g1, replace )
graph box mpg, by(foreign, rows(1)) name(g2, replace )

graph combine g1 g2 , ycom r(2)
```

This gives me the following results.

[image]

All works according to the manual so for but I have two problems with this output.
Firstly - aesthetics. Personally, I think plot with the same width across rows would look better.

Secondly, and more importantly - on more complex graphs the font size for categories, axes, etc. is also sized proportionally. So even if I specify, let's say - medium size of axis label on all graphs - some of them will be slightly bigger or smaller.

I was wondering if there is an option to programmatically force width of second row of box plots to have the same size as the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this you want? It is based on a trick, but the trick is quite general.

```
sysuse auto, clear
expand 2
gen what = cond(_n <= 74, rep78, 6 + foreign)
label def what 6 Domestic 7 Foreign
label val what what
graph box mpg, by(what, note("Repair record and Foreign") row(2) holes(8 9 10))
```

The logic is that

1. The two categorical variables are combined lengthwise. That ensures that each box plot will be the same size.
2. By specifying holes, we persuade `graph box` to put graphs on two rows.

I guess that your label size problem will disappear once 1 is solved.

For even more flexibility, you may need to abandon `graph box` and use `twoway` instead. A detailed discussion was given by me in the *Stata Journal* in 2009: you can go straight to http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0039