# How to align the x-axis in combined Stata bar graphs?

Tags: graph, stata

I am trying to stack multiple bar graphs on each other. I am using two constant variables in order to force Stata to print the first `over` option in colours and use the legend. Unfortunately, Stata does not automatically align the x-axis of the different graphs if I am using `graph combine`. Is there a proper way to left-align the x-axis? 
I have found a hack by adding blank spaces to the label of "con2" but this is not very exact and depends highly on the used font.

Here is a working example:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
graph drop _all
recode married south (1=100)
collapse married south, by(race)
list
gen con1 = 1
gen con2 = 1
graph bar married, horiz over(race) ///
    over(con1, lab(nolab)) over(con2, relabel(1 "Married")) ///
    legend(off) yscale(range(0 100)) ///
    name(plot1) fysize(42)
graph bar south, horiz over(race) ///
    over(con1, lab(nolab)) over(con2, relabel(1 "Lives in South")) ///
    yscale(range(0 100)) ///
    name(plot2)

graph combine plot1 plot2, cols(1) xcom ycom imargin(0 0 0 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing separate graphs and `graph combine` can only get so far in getting them aligned. The answer is to draw your separate graphs as separate panels of the same graph, which is easy with a restructuring of the data.

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
recode married south (1=100)
collapse married south, by(race)
list
rename (married south) (what=)
reshape long what , i(race) string j(response)
replace response = "lives in South" if response == "south"
graph hbar what, over(race) over(response) asyvars
```

The device applies to multiple panels, not just two. You might need to do a little work on the axis labels, as here.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast response! This hack saves me a lot of time (and code lines).

Comment: http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0058 shows the same basic idea in other contexts.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342210/in-stata-how-can-i-combine-box-plots-of-different-widths

Comment: Is there a possibilty to add an additional axis if I for example would also like to plot the mean age (which is also a variable in nlsw88) in the same graph?

Comment: On graphical grounds I don't see that the mean age belongs with means as percents, variables with different units. Nothing stops you putting different variables on the same scale, however, except good taste. The code is the same, really.

Comment: Maybe, I was unclear in my comment. I totally agree with you, that variables with different units would at least need different axes and would ideally not be plotted together in the same graph. However, sometimes space is everything and if I could include age in the same plot displaying e.g. the xaxis with percentages above and the xaxis with years below the plot region, I would do it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I don't know a way of declaring two axes with `graph bar` and its siblings.